# (SystemJS) core_1.provide is not a function

Tags: angular

I got recently by just reloading my Play Angular 2 project some dependencies issues, and I found some fix by upgrading to the RC6 of Angular 2. So I have all this like that :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
cache,
//angular2 dependencies
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__core" % "2.0.0-rc.6",
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__http" % "2.0.0-rc.6",
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__router" % "3.0.0-rc.2",
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__common" % "2.0.0-rc.6",
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__compiler" % "2.0.0-rc.6",
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__upgrade" % "2.0.0-rc.6",
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__platform-browser" % "2.0.0-rc.6",
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__platform-browser-dynamic" % "2.0.0-rc.6",
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__forms" % "2.0.0-rc.6",

"org.webjars.npm" % "core-js" % "2.4.1",
"org.webjars.npm" % "systemjs" % "0.19.37",
"org.webjars.npm" % "todomvc-common" % "1.0.2",
"org.webjars.npm" % "rxjs" % "5.0.0-beta.9",
"org.webjars.npm" % "zone.js" % "0.6.17",
"org.webjars.npm" % "typescript" % "2.0.0",

//tslint dependency
"org.webjars.npm" % "tslint-eslint-rules" % "1.3.0",
"org.webjars.npm" % "codelyzer" % "0.0.26",

//additional dependencies
"org.webjars.npm" % "moment" % "2.14.1",
"org.webjars.npm" % "ng2-bootstrap" % "1.0.24",
"org.webjars.npm" % "ng2-file-upload" % "1.0.3",
"org.webjars.npm" % "angular2-cookie" % "1.2.2",

"org.webjars.bower" % "bootstrap-sass" % "3.3.6" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
"commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4"
)
```

And in my @NgModule, I don't use any provide() in the providers.

That has fixed my previous compilation issues, but now I have only this error in my browser console :

```
zone.min.js:1 Error: (SystemJS) core_1.provide is not a function
```

And I have no other indications and the compilation goes well.
Has anyone already encountered that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie

*Please use 1.1.x versions for angular2 beta, 1.2.2 version is for release candidates earlier than rc.5 and 1.2.3 is for >rc.5.*

I am afraid my friend you are using the wrong version of angular2-cookie. Try updating to 1.2.3

Comment: Are you sure? I don't use any cookies or cookie module in my app. It seems the bundle version cant instantiate the component decorator. The unbundled version runs without error..